# esxi host remote driver update?

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, direct-attached-storage

We have a Power Edge R410 Server which is running on VmWare ESXi. Recently my boss has been making an update from 5 to 5.1 and the datastore has been gone. We try to recover and seems like the problem is related to the scsi driver .How do we make driver updates if the server is not on place. Can I do a remote driver update on Host?

```
lspci | grep LSI
```

shows me the mass storage controller

```
00:03:00.0 Mass storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic Dell PERC H200 Adapter [vmhba0]
```

from sphere client is not available and all the virtual machines are inaccessible 
 Practically we see just our 2 QNAPS in the datastore

df -h

```
Filesystem Size   Used Available Use% Mounted on
NFS        3.6T 533.7G      3.1T  15% /vmfs/volumes/Terraserver
NFS        5.4T   1.7T      3.7T  32% /vmfs/volumes/qnap_backup
```

I can't add any new Network Adapter

[image]

Comment: Of course you can.  [For that matter, there's even a customized Dell ESXi ISO you can use to install or update your host with in the first place](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=YGH6K). But with the 0 details you've given us, this question is pretty useless.  Install driver updates the same way you'd install firmware updates on the server. (DRAC and/or the lifecycle controller, if you have them, are the best way.)  And if you don't install firmware updates now, well... it's probably something you should start doing, so learn how.

Comment: okay sir you are right I just try to learn here new things and that's why I'm asking. So the guy simply has been doing a lot of things without no reason  and now the attached hard disk is not visible and we have a lot VM's on it hich are now inaccesibble

Comment: Just update the drivers, it's simple, if you can't do this you shouldn't be in charge of supporting them

Comment: yes I try to find the appropiate driver but I do not find. the binaries what I found on dell page won't execute like `chmod +x driver.bin and than ./driver.bin`